# optimization of lift to drag ratio

Tags: calculus

***Please look at the attached picture. It contains an picture that describes the relationship between the angles.***

Consider a supersonic airplane wing with a cross-section in the shape of a thin diamond in which the half-angle of the opening is $\tau$ and the attack angle $\alpha$.

$$
\frac{lift}{drag} = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha^2 + \tau^2}
$$

Part a) For a given $\tau$, find the best attack angle $\alpha$, that is, the one that maximizes the ratio of $\mathit{lift}/\mathit{drag}$. Part b) Find the minimum (largest negative) ratio.

[Here is the problem with picture (number  2D-1).](https://i.imgur.com/h3vqMRG) Apologies for the messy work, I shorthanded $D = \mathit{lift}/\mathit{drag}$

my answer for part a)

$$
\frac{d}{d\alpha} \left(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha^2 + \tau^2}\right) = \frac{-\alpha^2 + \tau^2}{(\alpha^2 + \tau^2)^2}\\
0 = \frac{-\alpha^2 + \tau^2}{(\alpha^2 + \tau^2)^2}\\
\alpha^2 = \tau^2\\
\alpha = \pm\tau\\
$$
checking extrema
$$
f(\alpha) = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha^2 + \tau^2}\\
f(\tau) = \frac{1}{2\tau}\\
f(0) = 0\\
f(-\tau) = \frac{-1}{2\tau}\\
f(\pi/2) = \frac{\pi}{\frac{\pi^2}{2} + 2\tau^2}\\
f(\tau) > f(0) > f(-\tau)
$$
I could not verify that $f(\tau) > f(\pi/2)$.

my answer for part b)

$\alpha = \pi/2$

Answer: because $0<\tau<\pi/2$, $0<\alpha<\pi/2$

a) $\alpha = \tau$

b) $\alpha = -\tau$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't have an answer key, so I don't even know if I'm approaching it correctly, let alone if my answers are right.

Comment: How can we tell if you are approaching correctly, if you share your answer without any justification?

Comment: done. Added work.

Comment: Your result in a) is OK. But you did not prove if it was a maximum or a minimum. And it is not very "clean" (where does $\alpha^2=\tau^2$ comes from? (of course I know but it does not show)

Comment: added more work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you took the square root you lost a $\pm$ sign. That is useful for the minimum

Comment: Added. However, I still could not verify the extremum $f(\pi/2)$.

Comment: I think you have to assume that $0 \lt \tau \lt \frac \pi 2$.  Otherwise there is a cavity at the front of the wing.  In fact it will be much smaller than $\frac \pi 2$.  Then you get there.